# Using CefSharp and a SchemeHandler how to create a Javascript File()

Tags: javascript, cefsharp

On a website I am automating with the help of Cefsharp I have the need to provide a javascript [File.File()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File). The file I want to give it is locally saved and could be anything from pdfs to office documents or images.  As far as CefSharp is concerned I have implemented a ISchemeHandlerFactory and ResourceHandler adding a test:// scheme and for example I have successfully added a JS file like this.

```
var head = document.head;
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'test://local/folder/mytest.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

According to the API to create a file I need

> **bits** - An Array of ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, Blob, or DOMString objects — or a mix of any such objects. This is the file content encoded as UTF-8.

So I have my scheme of test:// to give me a local file what do I need to use in javascript to get this into a file?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: many things. And also put an answer. Still have 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issues which is looking like another question as I really am guessing what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it. I first tried a fetch but that would not let me use a custom scheme.  So I had to use XMLHttpRequest

```
(function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var contentType = xhttp.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
            var file = new File([this.response],'3Markets.xlsx', {type: contentType,});
            //use my new file etc
      }
   };
xhttp.open('GET', 'test://local/folder/3Markets.xlsx', true);
xhttp.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhttp.send(); 
})()
```

The only issue or worry i have is I currently have to call

```
CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-web-security", "disable-web-security")
```

which i will have to have a look around how I can achieve this without disabling web security or eventually ask a question here.

Comment: See http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_Cef_AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry.htm look at project source for an example