# How do I add a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to a requested resource with a custom scheme with CefSharp

Tags: cefsharp

Using a [XMLHttpRequest which is the subject of my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54391137/using-cefsharp-and-a-schemehandler-how-to-create-a-javascript-file?noredirect=1#comment95600909_54391137) with a custom scheme I am loading local files.  To test I used the disable-web-security argument but I do not want to use the browser with this disabled.

Once disable-web-security is enabled then I get

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How (or where) can I add this to the header or otherwise fix it.

First I have tried to use the AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry but I do not know what to put in.  My Scheme is test:// and I call for example test://local/folder/3Markets.xlsx.  The webpage origin is https://product.company.de

```
CefSharp.Cef.AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry("test://local", "test", "product.company.de", True)
```

and this

```
CefSharp.Cef.AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry("test://local", "test", "", True)
```

But honestly I don't understand what I am supposed to put here.

I also thought that I can fix this issue with my custom scheme handling.

```
Dim cs As New CefCustomScheme With {
        .SchemeName = DBSchemeHandler.DBSchemeName,
        .SchemeHandlerFactory = New DBSchemeHandler,
        .IsStandard = True,   'DONT THINK THIS IS NEEDED
        .IsCorsEnabled = True   'DONT THINK THIS IS NEEDED
    }
    dbSurferSettings.RegisterScheme(cs)
```

I thought in the response I would need to add this header. Or is it the request?

```
Public Overrides Function GetResponse(response As IResponse, ByRef responseLength As Long, ByRef redirectUrl As String) As Stream

Dim aURI As New Uri(response)
Dim fileName As String = aURI.AbsolutePath

Dim bytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)
Dim mStream = New MemoryStream(bytes)

If mStream Is Nothing Then
    Return Nothing
Else
    Stream = mStream
    Stream.Position = 0
    responseLength = Stream.Length
    Dim fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName)
    MimeType = GetMimeType(fileExtension)
    StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    Return mStream
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Read http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_Cef_AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry.htm again,  you have your source and target mixed up.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone reviewing this. Amaitland's comments have corrected my issues.

The domain of the website is https://product.company.de and my scheme is test.  Thus one way is as follow.

```
CefSharp.Cef.AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry("https://product.company.de", "test", "", True)
```

Also the other thing I was doing incorrectly is I was adding this at application start up.  But it was returning false.  You need to add this once the browser is actually on the website with in my example https://product.company.de. Setting it with all the other settings at startup means it returns falls.  I have put it into the FrameLoadEnd event.

Comment: The earliest possible place you can call `AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry` is in http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserProcessHandler_OnContextInitialized.htm 
Pass your instance of `IBrowserProcessHandler` to the `Cef.Initialize` overload http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_Cef_Initialize_2.htm